# can't resize an image using php

Tags: php, image

I have a php code to get an image and resize it. Can't get the output as expected.. Please help me figure out what the exact problem is..!!

```
<?php
$picture_source = 'image.png';
if ($picture_source != null){
  $img1=file_get_contents($picture_source);
  $new_img1 = resizeImage($img1, 200, 200);
  file_put_contents("i1.png", $new_img1);
}

function resizeImage($img,$newwidth,$newheight) {
  list($width, $height) = getimagesizefromstring($img);
  $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
  imagecopyresampled($thumb, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);
  return $thumb;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got some confusion with your variable names and types. You're trying to deal with a filename, the file contents, and an image resource at the same time, and you're using the wrong ones for a few of the functions.

`imagecopyresampled` takes two image resources (source and destination), but you're passing it the file contents in place of the source.

`file_put_contents` takes a string for the file contents, but you're passing it the resized image resource.

PHP has native functions for reading the image dimensions and creating an image resource from a filename, so you shouldn't need to ever have the source file contents available as a string.

If you change a few of the variable names and function calls around, you end up with:

```
<?php
$sourceFilename = 'image.png';

if ($sourceFilename != null){
  $newImg = resizeImage($sourceFilename, 200, 200);
  imagepng($newImg, "i1.png");
}

function resizeImage($imgFilename, $newWidth, $newHeight) {
  list($width, $height) = getimagesize($imgFilename);

  $img = imagecreatefrompng($imgFilename);
  $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);

  imagecopyresampled($thumb, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $width, $height);

  return $thumb;
}
```

Also, you should turn on PHP notices and warnings in your development environment - they will have been trying to help you.

Comment: It results a complete black image..  @iainn

Comment: @VikranthAyu Updated. There were a few other problems in your original code as well.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. But it works well when I read and create jpeg images not well with png images

Comment: Yes, I just faced this issue myself. JPG is working fine but PNG results in black images. Weird.